# CallKit Video button disabled

Tags: ios, swift, callkit, cxprovider

I have integrated CallKit successfully and I'm trying to handle the video button. In some devices, I get the enabled video button and can request to open a video connection. But for some devices, I get a disabled video icon. What could be the reason for that?

```
private lazy var provider: CXProvider = {
    let configuration = CXProviderConfiguration()
    configuration.supportsVideo = true
    configuration.maximumCallGroups = 2
    configuration.maximumCallsPerCallGroup = 4
    configuration.includesCallsInRecents = false
    configuration.supportedHandleTypes = [.generic]
    return CXProvider(configuration: configuration)
}()

func reportIncomingCall() {
    let uuid = UUID()

    let update = CXCallUpdate()
    update.supportsGrouping = true
    update.supportsHolding = true
    update.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .generic, value: "Name")
    update.hasVideo = true // or false

    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: update) { [weak self] error in
      // handle 
    }
}
```

[image]

Note: Whatsapp has the enabled video button in the same device.

Comment: Did you try removing 'update.hasVideo' assignment from the reportIncomingCall() function altogether since you're always setting it to true.

Comment: Hey @iOSDeveloper, Yes I did and there's no difference from that.

Comment: Check the video permission for you app in the settings.

Comment: Hey @ChetanA, which permission exactly are you referring to?

Comment: As you have highlighted the example of Whatsapp in your question, I would suggest you to check the permission of both the Watsapp and your application on the device. If you disable the Microphone and Camera then you will not be able to make  video calls and button would be disabled.

Comment: Hey @ChetanA, Those permissions do not seem to affect the video button. I have enabled both Mic and Camera permissions.